# What is VideoEvent.READY in ActionScript 3?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, flv, preloading

I am curious as to what the "VideoEvent.READY" in ActionScript 3 is for. So, consider this code:

```
myFLVPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, myMethod);
```

I looked up the constant in the ActionScript reference guide, but their definition was very poor. Does anyone know what the above code will accomplish? Will it listen when the source video of the FLVPlayback component has loaded its source video and is ready to go?

Comment: Friendly request: the greetings and signatures are redundant on Stack Overflow (which is not a message board); please leave them out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... yes. I was right. It either waits until the target video has downloaded, or the video has been pulled out of cache and is ready to go!